# Error Python TypeError

Tags: python

Hola estoy haciendo un programa que lo que hace a grandes rasgos es permitirte registrar y despues iniciar sesion y a la hora de terminar de colocar la contrasenia en iniciar sesion me da el error TypeError pero no encuentro el codigo que da el error pero sospecho que es que no esta "procesando" la contrasenia anteriormente pasada a hashlib(creo que asi se diria).

Aqui el codigo que teorizo que da error en la aprte de 'descifrado' de contrasenias:

`usuario.py`

```
from usuarios import conexion
import datetime
import hashlib

connect = conexion.conectar()
database = connect[0]
cursor = connect[1]

class Usuario:

    def __init__(self, nombre, apellidos, email, password):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellidos = apellidos
        self.email = email
        self.email = email
        self.password = password

    def registrar(self):
        fecha = datetime.datetime.now()

        # Cifrar contrasenia
        cifrado = hashlib.sha256()
        cifrado.update(self.password.encode('utf8'))

        sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES(null, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        usuario = (self.nombre, self.apellidos, self.email, cifrado.hexdigest(), fecha)

        try:
            cursor.execute(sql, usuario)
            database.commit()
            result = [cursor.rowcount, self]
        except:
            result = [0, self]

        return result
    def identificar(self):

        sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = %s and password = %s"

        # Cifrar contrasenia
        cifrado = hashlib.sha256()
        cifrado.update(self.password.encode('utf8'))

        # Datos para la consulta
        usuario = (self.email, cifrado.hexdigest())
        cursor.execute(sql, usuario)
        result = cursor.fetchone()

        return result
```

y aqui el resto del codigo junto al orden en que va:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`conexion.py`

```
import mysql.connector

def conectar():
    database = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="",
        database="master_python",
        port=3306
    )

    cursor = database.cursor(buffered=True)

    return [database, cursor]
```

`acciones.py(usuarios)`

```
import usuarios.usuario as modelo
class Acciones:

    def registro(self):
        print("\nVamos aregistrarte...")

        nombre = input("Ingrese su nombre: ")
        apellidos = input("Ingrese su apellido: ")
        password = input("Introduzca sus contrasenia: ")
        email = input('Intruduzca su email: ')
        usuario = modelo.Usuario(nombre, apellidos, email, password)
        registro = usuario.registrar()

        if registro[0] >= 1:
            """
            print(f"Perfecto {registro[1].nombre} te has registrado con el email {registro[1].email}")
            """
        else:
            print("Error al registrar...")

    def login(self):
        print("\nIniciemos sesion...")

        try:
            email = input("Ingresa tu email: ")
            password = input("Introduce tu contrasenia: ")

            usuario = modelo.Usuario('', '', email, password)
            login = modelo.Usuario.identificar()

            if email == login[3]:
                print(f"\nBienvenido {login[1]}, te has registrado en el sistema el {login[5]}")
                self.proximasAcciones(login)
        except Exception as e:
            print(type(e))
            print(type(e).__name__)
            print(f"Login incorrecto, intentalo mas tarde.")

    def proximasAcciones(self, usuario):
        print("""
        Acciones disponibles:
        - Crear nota (crear)
        - Mostrar tus notas (mostrar)
        - Eliminar nota (eliminar)
        - Salir (salir)
        """)

        accion = input("Introduzca la accion a realizar: ")

        if accion == "crear":
            print("\nProcedamos a crear.")
            self.proximasAcciones(usuario)

        elif accion == "mostrar":
            print("\nProcedamos a mostrar.")
            self.proximasAcciones(usuario)
```

`nota.py`

```
import usuarios.conexion as conexion

connect = conexion.conectar()
database = connect[0]
cursor = connect[1]


class Nota:

    def __init__(self, usuario_id, titulo, descripcion):
        self.usuario_id = usuario_id
        self.titulo = titulo
        self.descripcion = descripcion

    def guardar(self):
        sql = "INSERT INTO notas VALUES(null, %s, %s, %s, NOW())"
        nota = (self.usuario_id, self.titulo, self.descripcion)

        cursor.execute(sql, nota)
        database.commit()
        return [cursor.rowcount, self]
```

`acciones.py(notas)`

```
from notas import nota as modelo

class Acciones:

    def crear(self, usuario):
        print(f"De acuerdo{usuario}, creando una nueva nota...")
        titulo = input("Introduce el titulo de tu nota: ")
        descripcion = input("Introduce la descripcion de tu nota: ")

        nota = modelo.Nota(usuario[0], titulo, descripcion)
        guardar = nota.guardar()

        if guardar[0] >= 1:
            print("Se ha guardado correctamente la nota: ")
        else:
            print("\nHan habido problemas al intentar guardar la nota...")
```

Comment: Sería de gran ayuda que añadieras el error completo que te da. No podemos revisar todo tu código para averiguar qué puede estar fallando.